# Capture motion in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I want to capture the motion of a red paper on a white background in Linux using Python? I will be using OpenCV and an image library to create images at 30fps. Is there a way I can detetmine the position of the red paper (or a point on it) without going through every pixel in the image, since that would make it horribly slow.  Or is there a better way of doing this altogether?

The code for reading the webcam is posted [here](http://www.jperla.com/blog/post/capturing-frames-from-a-webcam-on-linux).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the full code, but for [yellow paper](https://github.com/abidrahmank/OpenCV-Python/blob/master/Other_Examples/track_yellow_draw_line.py). Change color range in line 18 for red color.
And it works only if single yellow paper is present.

And here is another [code for the same](https://github.com/abidrahmank/OpenCV-Python/blob/master/Other_Examples/single_color_multiple_points_track.py), but now it works even if more than one yellow paper is present. Again change it to red yourself.